# Google map api 3 geokoder неправильные результаты

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

По запросу `98 LATHROP ROAD, BOX 147 PLAINFIELD CT 06374 United States` геокодер выдает [не совсем верные результаты](http://jsfiddle.net/HhLh6).

При этом на гуглмап серч страничке [результат правильный](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Central+Auto+Group/@41.6630944,-71.9109546,17z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1s98+LATHROP+ROAD,+BOX+147+PLAINFIELD+CT+06374+United+States!3m1!1s0x0:0xcc630370e2f5d80a).

Comment: если из адреса убрать Box 147 (по которому он улицу пытается определить), то будет найдено что нужно. У вас кстати разные запросы, в прямой ссылке явно координаты есть, т.е. что конкретно ищете не так важно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov да, без коробки работает норм. Но по текущему запросу ембед версия и поиск на гугл пейдж (а координаты он вставляет в ссылку после поиска) показывает верный результат в отличии от геокодера. Менять сам запрос - не очень хорошо, ткк есть уже база с этими данными.

Comment: @SomeName, я думаю, что maps уточняет поиск поисковыми запросами гугла (как например google voice), геокодер чисто по адресам работает, воспринимает всю строку, поэтому и разница есть. все-таки box 147 это адресат, а не часть адреса в терминах топонимики. даже не знаю как бы задачу решал, про загрницу вообще не в курсе как там что, в россии - кладр со товарищи в помощь могут быть...